# Accessing parent controller $scope data after load in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise, angular-controller

I have the following situation in angular:

1. I load json data from a database on init() to a variable "data" and would like to use the variable "data" in a child controller (nested).
2. Because the loading from the database takes some time, the variable $scope.data in the child controller outputs as "undefined".

What is an elegant way to handle this situation? Do I need to use a promise on parent's init method inside the child controller? I would appreciate an example :).

```
// Parent Controller
app.controller('pCTRL', function($scope) {
  $scope.init = function(id){} 
  //sets my variable $scope.data successfully via a rest API
  //and for test, sets $scope.x to "blabla"
}

//Child Controller
app.controller('cCTRL', function($scope) {
console.log($scope.x); //outputs blabla properly
console.log($scope.data); // undefined
```

Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: There are lots of ways to handle this depending on your use case. Are you trying to transform the parent data on initialization from within the child controller, or are you just trying to show it in the child's template?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Indeed, the child controller is 1) showing the data and  2) transforming it (appending new objects).

Comment: I found a conversation about designing such data exchange here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012385/parent-and-child-controller-data-design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common solution is to use a watcher. For example:

```
app.controller('cCTRL', function($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('data', function(newVal){
        console.log(newVal); // outputs actual value
    });
}
```

This is only needed if you need to have logic in the directive. If you just want to display `data` in the `cCTRL` template you don't need the above watcher, angular will update the template when the parent changes.